# Difference between rm -rf *o and rm -rf *.o

Tags: shell, rm

I'm wondering if the two commands (1) rm -rf *o and (2) rm -rf *.o give the same result: both delete the object files.

Moreover why the above commands delete the executable files as well?

Comment: The first command will remove any files that end with o and the second will delete all files ending with a dot and then o.

Answer (score 3):

`*` is a shell pattern matching anything except for hidden files.

`rm -rf *o` will thus also delete a file called `hello` or `test.iso`, whereas `rm -rf *.o` will only delete files ending in `.o`.

By the way, `-r` means *recursive*, i.e. will delete directories too. It should not be present here. You want `rm -f *.o`.

Comment: your reply is very helpful

Comment: And you probably don't want `-f` either.

Comment: `* is a shell pattern matching anything.` - anything except for hidden files

Comment: @glennjackman `-f` is typical in a clean script, as it makes it idempotent. `rm *.o` fails noisily if nothing has been compiled or clean has just been executed.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if the two commands (1) rm -rf *o and (2) rm -rf *.o give the same result: both delete the object files.

No, they don't give the same result:

1. Deletes all files that end with `o` as well as all directories that end with `o`.
2. Deletes all files that end with `.o` as well as all directories that end with `.o`.

> Moreover why the above commands delete the executable files as well?

Probably because they end with `o` (1) or `.o` (2).